Reasons for downvoting
In other SE sites, they have a system where if you downvote a question or answer, you also provide a comment stating why you're downvoting it.
This gives askers and answerers the opportunity to realise their mistake/improve upon their questions and answers.
I notice this isn't in play on https://chinese.stackexchange.com/ and I think it should be. It's a good system.
EDIT: P.S.: similarly, commenting with reasons for upvoting are also appreciated and helps askers/answerers know they're on the right track, and why.

No. You are encouraged to leave a comment for your neg vote; you don't have to. THAT is the policy on all the stackexchange sites I've been on. Please link to a policy that says otherwise.

I am quite surprise by the down-vote on your latest question immediately after I gave it an up-vote. I agree that it is right to give an explanation if the reason for down-voting is not obvious. On the other hand, there are also clear-cut cases where one-liner opinion-based answers or English-only questions are up voted with no rhyme or reason.
There is nothing you can do about it really, except hoping for someone within the community to cast a neutralizing vote. In general, it does happen. One swallow does not make a summer, so don't fret over it.

Thanks for the reassurance, and I'll try to do as you say ^_^

In SE sites there is no obligation to leave a comment explaining a downvote. It is nicer to do so as the author can find out how to improve the question, but the only thing for the downvoter is a short popup encouraging downvoters to comment. See this discussion:
Encouraging people to explain downvotes
Having said that, on low-traffic SEs like Chinese.SE, there will be more noise in general (e.g. downvote on something that doesn't have obvious flaws, or upvote on something obviously bad), so try not to worry about it. Don't jump to the conclusion that it's people out to get you.
